# ArcGIS JS API join ArcGIS Online layers

Tags: arcgis-online, attribute-joins, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am attempting to join 2 layers from the same ArcGIS Online service together, using ESRI's limited [sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-dynamicdatalayer-table-join/index.html?search=table%20source) for MapImageLayer.  I would like to join the first [ID: 0] and second [ID: 1] layers in my service together using the "FLOORID" field, which both layers have.

```
var floors = new MapImageLayer({
    url: baseURL, //my service URL
    title: "All Layers",
    sublayers: [{
            title: "InteriorSpace",
            id: 1,
            opacity: 0.75,
            source: {
                type: "data-layer",
                dataSource: {
                    type: "join-table",
                    leftTableSource: {
                        type: "map-layer",
                        mapLayerId: 0
                    },
                    rightTableSource: {
                        type: "data-layer",
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "map-layer",
                            mapLayerId: 1 
                        }                                                                                             
                    }
                },
                leftTableKey: "FLOORID",
                rightTableKey: "FLOORID",
                joinType: "left-inner-join"
            }
        }]
});
```

The console doesn't log any errors, but I do not get any tiles displayed.  What am I missing?

Comment: It appears the same JS API functionality for services published to ArcGIS Online are not the same for those published to ArcGIS Server/Enterprise.  Am i reading documentation correctly?

Comment: Correct, the functionality can differ slightly between server/enterprise vs ArcGIS Online, similar to how it can differ between different versions of server/enterprise.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this one? I have exact same issue.  That sample relies on dynamic workspaces which is unique to an ArcGIS GIS Server.

Comment: @Simon I did not.  I ended up setting up ArcGIS Server on a local server VM.  Very frustrating trying to get anywhere with the JS API.